# Find missing yield statements

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, yield

I'm looking for a way to find places in code (like validating with jslint in Atom) where function is defined with *, but when calling it has no "yield" specified. I forgetting to "yield" too often and would like something to remind/validate this for me. Is there a way? Atom Package maybe?

To illustrate and example:

```
let f = function* () {
  yield doAsyncStuff();
  yield doMoreAsyncStuff();
  let res = yield fetchAsyncStuff();
  return res;
}

let caller = function* () {
  yield anotherFunction();
  let res = x(); // <-- here I have missed the yield
}
```

Comment: Unit test, huh? :)

Comment: I kinda feel that mistakes like these can be caught much easier than writing a test. Besides, I can't count how many times I have encountered this also when testing. It costs time debugging anyway, no matter where you run into this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Eslint](http://eslint.org) has a rule called [`require-yield`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-yield) which detects if there is no `yield` keyword used in a generator function. BUT in your `caller` function, you already have one `yield` when calling `anotherFunction`, and since not using `yield` when calling `x` function could be part of the logic behind your code, there is no logical way to detect the missing `yield` there.
By the way this issue is pretty much discussed and not feasible: [Rule Idea: Ensure yield on call to generator function](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/5193)

Comment: How can not using "yield" be part of logic? What's the point of calling that generator function then, if it is never yielded?

Comment: The is yield in the function Andree. You have `yield anotherFunction();`. Then after yield you can modify some state of do other work. And that is true that the is no point to have generator function with no yield and there is eslint rule for it `require-yield `. But it is not you case.

Comment: @andree you might want to save the result of the `x` function which could be a promise as a simple variable to do parallel operations, or other types of algorithms, like saving the actual generator object in the memory and iterate over that later.

Comment: @MehranHatami thanks, you make a good point there. Is there anyway I can force linter to always assume that I want to yield, never leave as simple variable for later operations?

Comment: @andree one of the use-cases I had was to send different generator objects in a list and let the one who calls my function decide to `yield` on my generators when it is needed.

Comment: @andree You could create a custom eslint rule for that. I also think it is a good idea to have a rule like this. check out this post for creating custom rules: [Writing custom EsLint rules](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/05/27/writing-custom-eslint-rules/)

Comment: Did a little digging and this is pretty much discussed and not feasible - https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/5193 Please add this link to answer to make it complete.

Comment: @andree thanks for the tip, just updated the answer.